# cProfiler: How to get stat by execution order?

Tags: python, python-2.7, profiling, profiler

I'd like to get stat of profiler ordered and grouped not by number of calls and not by time spent but by **natural execution order**.

For example, if we use cProfiler for the next simple program:

```
def my_sleep0():
    sleep( 0.05 )

def my_sleep1():
    sleep( 0.15 )
    my_sleep2()

def my_sleep2():
    my_sleep3()

def my_sleep3():
    sleep( 0.1 )


if __name__ == '__main__':

    p = Profiler( './' ) # a wrapper for cProfiler, cProfiler starts here

    i = 10

    for i in range( 1, 5 ):
        i += 100
        my_sleep0()
        my_sleep1()
        my_sleep1()

    # cProfiler destructs and ends here
```

I want a stat by natural execution order, for example:

```
Ordered by: execution

calling_function    cumtime backtrace

test.py:36(my_sleep0)   <cumtime>  test.py:43()
test.py:39(my_sleep1)   <cumtime>  test.py:44()
test.py:43(my_sleep2)   <cumtime>  test.py:20 called by test.py:44(my_sleep1)
test.py:43(my_sleep3)   <cumtime>  test.py:25 called by test.py:20(my_sleep1)->test.py:26(my_sleep2)
test.py:39(my_sleep1)   <cumtime>  test.py:45()
test.py:43(my_sleep2)   <cumtime>  test.py:20 called by test.py:25(my_sleep1)
test.py:43(my_sleep3)   <cumtime>  test.py:25 called by test.py:20(my_sleep1)->test.py:26(my_sleep2)
...
```

(`<cumtime>` is a numeric time.)

**Are there ways in Python to achieve it? How?**

Addition.

My code of Profiler() does not do it now:

```
class Profiler:
    def __init__( self, dir ):
        self._profiler = cProfile.Profile()
        self._profiler.enable()

        self._dir = dir # profiler output is "/tmp/profiler/{key}/<files_here>"


    def stop( self ):
        profilerDir = self._dir

        self._profiler.disable()

        with open( os.path.join( profilerDir, datetime.now().strftime( "%d-%m-%y %H.%M.%S" ) ), 'w' ) as f:
            stat = pstats.Stats( self._profiler, stream = f ).sort_stats( 'pcalls' )
            stat.print_stats()  
            stat.print_callers()
            stat.print_callees()


    def __del__( self ):
        self.stop()
```

Comment: @KillianDS OK. But it seems the cProfiler does not have the feature. I wonder is there a tool or a method to achieve what I want.

Comment: You can sort by line. Why exactly would you want to sort by time of (first?) execution? What does that gain you?

Comment: @KillianDS I'd like to sort by execution order, not by execution time. Excuse me.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant, I still don't see why you'd want to do that (`why` is often more crucial information than `how` in order to end up with a correct answer).

Comment: @KillianDS It's difficult for me to figure out from where `some` was called. I want to link the profiler's stat with a real code easily. It's like when you measure time before some action, then after some action, and then saves the information to a stat file: the time difference and a current call stack. And in this order only - the order of execution.

Comment: The backtrace shows where things were called from, the file & line shows what took the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but in many cases it is not a sensible thing to do as one (slow) part of the code may be called many times in the execution, what you could do is to run a trace and use the output of that to sort the profile entries.

I.e. trace tells you the order of execution and that can be used to sort the profile data.

I would seriously consider taking a look at profile viewer tools such as [runsnakerun](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RunSnakeRun) for this, e.g. the following lets me see how much time was taken and where it was called from:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to do it? A special features, methods which don't slow down much?

Comment: As I said - trace will give you an order of execution - parse the results, which includes file, line, function information, and those for profile, which includes file, line function information, and *sort* the profile results on the execution order.  Then output the result.  In any complex situation it will be nearly useless.

Comment: Can I use the trace on a production server with many users where the slowdown problem occurs sometimes?

Comment: If you are running on a production server you a) will be running complex code, b) probably shouldn't even be running the profiler & c) are at the mercy of things outside of your python code that the profiler will not accurately reflect.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I start the profiler on a production server but only for my user (if user_id=my_user_id).